# Array indexing assignment to the same element multiple times

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

This is a rather basic question so I suspect it must have been asked before. My apologies if this is the case, I couldn't find it.

Anyway, as we know we can use an array `ind` to index another array `x`:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,0,0,0,0])
ind = np.array([0,2,4])
x[ind] += np.array([1,2,3])
print(x)
```

Which as expected outputs

```
[1 0 2 0 3]
```

Changing `ind` to have recurring indices, e.g. `[0,2,2]`, results in assignment only for the last of the recurring index

```
[1 0 3 0 0]
```

instead of

```
[1 0 5 0 0]
```

While I find this behavior very unsatisfying and counter-intuitive I understand it is because an underlying temporary array is used as described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html).

Anyhow, the question is, is there any nice way to achieve this? I could of course just use a loop, but I'd rather like to learn an elegant and efficient way. (Note: This is not my real code, just a minimal example of the problem I stumbled upon).

Thank you.

Comment: Look into `np.add.at`.

Comment: @Divakar: Exactly what I needed! Thanks :)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to elaborate how I can improve upon my question?

Comment: Not sure about the downvote, but linked a dup on it. `bincount` would be efficient here.

Comment: @Divakar: Yeah, that's fine :) I'm happy as long as I got my solution. I expected something like that was already answered, I apparently just couldn't think of the right terms to search for.